# Usage of the term Baali

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, theology, hosea-hoshea

In [Hosea 2:18](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16156#v=18), if G-d was called "Baali," does this allude to the concept that God was perceived as a bull as Baal was portrayed in Ugaritic texts?

Comment: Do you mean Hosea 2:15? ופקדתי עליה את ימי הבעלים

Comment: I don't see any use of any term related to בעל in Hosea 2:16

Comment: I'm also unfamiliar with Ugaritic, so I apologize if I'm being misplaced, but בעלי simply means "my master".  I don't know if you can make any connection with this relatively common Hebrew term.

Comment: Hosea 2:16 has "my master" which is what Baal means. Usually Baal is depicted as a bull, so if G-d is called Baali does that mean G-d was thought of as a bull as well? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see "my master" in 2:16... maybe the numbering is different

Comment: Do you have the Hebrew original? Which edition are you using?

Comment: I'm using the NIV Bible actually, haha. Sorry, maybe the word Baali is not found in the Hebrew translation.

Comment: To answer your question though, Baal just means master.  The semitic god which with God is most associated would be El, not Baal, and the similarity is only that people called the object of their worship Baal.  I am not aware of any situation in which God was depicted as a bull or thought of as a bull; calling your god "master" then as now, was common in many different religions.

Comment: You might be looking at _Hoshe'a_ 2:18, in which "_Ba'l_", appears in parallel with the synonymous "_Ish_".

Comment: I edited your question because I believe that your Bible and mine have different numberings, and that @WAF's guess was probably correct. If you think my guess was wrong, you can always [edit] your own questions to fix them up

Answer (score 6):

**No.**

As WAF [pointed out](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/51257/usage-of-the-term-baali#comment135777_51257), the word is used synonymously in [that verse](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16156#v=18) with the word "אישי," "my husband," so that the word means "my husband" in context.

[Rashi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi) to that verse [explains](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16156#v=18&showrashi=true):

> **בעלי.** לשון אדנות ומורא ורבותינו פירשו ככלה בבית חמיה ולא ככלה בבית אביה
>
> **Baali:** An expression of mastership and fear. And our Rabbis ([Pesachim 87a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=87&format=pdf), [Kethuboth 71b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=15&daf=71b&format=pdf)) explained: Like a bride in her
>   father-in-law’s house, and not like a bride in her father’s house.

( *Chabad (Judaica Press) translation* )

Rashi teaches us that the word means "husband," particularly in the sense of the husband being the "man of the house," the one in control; as opposed to "Ishi/אישי," which also means "my husband," but with a different connotation:

> תעבדוני מאהבה ולא מיראה אישי לשון אישות וחיבת נעורים
>
> [...] Ishi is an expression of marriage and the love of one’s youth.

( *Chabad (Judaica Press) translation* )